# How to refresh my page after my last function is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a javascript program after I press my enter key, it will finish executing the program then my page will refresh. I try to add an if loop inside my last function but it not working.

Hope someone can help me out with my coding. As I'm really new to HTML CSS and javascript.

The bottom will be my program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
<style>
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* background-position: center; */
    background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
  }

  .robot_start_top {
    top: 280px;
    transition: top 2s;
  }

  .robot_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    transition: all 2s;
  }

  .robot_end_left {
    left: 570px;
  }

  .robot_end_top {
    top: 180px;
  }

  .robot1_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 570px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot1_end_left {
    left: 520px;
  }

  .robot2_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 520px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot2_end_left {
    left: 470px;
  }
  .robot3_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 470px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot3_end_left {
    left: 420px;
  }

  .robot3_start_right {
    position: fixed;
    left: 470px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }
  .robot3_start_down {
    position: fixed;
    left: 180px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot3_end_down {
    top: 280px;
  }

  .robot3_end_right {
    left: 570px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body onkeydown="move(event)">
<div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
  <img id="robot" style= width:30px; height:40px" src="pic_8.PNG">
</div>

<script>
  var move = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 97) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
      }, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
      }, 2000);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 98) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
      }, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
      }, 2000);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 99) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      appDiv.classList.add("robot2_end_left");
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 100) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_left");
    }

      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
        setTimeout(function() {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function() {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
        }, 0);

        window.location = '';
      }

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're having a JavaScript issue, tag JS, not java. **java != javascript**

Comment: 140 lines of (bad) code just for a reload problem, next time make it short => https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow  && https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`window.location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) at the end of your function

You might have to use `setTimeout(window.location.reload(true), 0)` to set the reload to the end of the execution stack, however

```js
var move = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 97) {
        // Code
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 98) {
        // Code
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 99) {
        // Code
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 100) {
        // Code
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Code
    }

    setTimeout(window.location.reload(true), 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I try using your method but it not working. The page refresh before my keycode 13 execute. Hope you would help me. thanks

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the setTimeout would work okay with how this was being done; and I don't see how you could use promises without bigger changes to your code

Comment: Your best bet might be simply incrementing a value for each timeout, then using that in the final setTimeout - https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/dyPVaja